# Ajustar imagem ao tamanho da <div>

Tags: html, css

Bem, estou criando uma mini rede social mas estou tendo um pequeno problema, a imagem do perfil não se adapta a div.

[image: Foto de perfil]

Meu código é:

```
<div class="profilepic"></div>

<style>
.profilepic {
width: 150px;
height: 150px;
border-radius: 50%;
background-image: url(url da foto de perfil);
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-attachment: fixed;
background-position: center;
</style>
```

Comment: É só mudar o tamanho em width (largura) e height (altura).

Comment: Poderia explicar melhor?

Comment: É sempre bom manter a imagem de perfil no HTML e não no CSS para ajudar no SEO.

Comment: Bem observado !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Não entendi bem o que quer, mas seria isso?

```css
.profile{
    width: 60px;
    height: 60px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.profile img{
    width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="profile">
        <img src="https://s-media-cache-ak0.pinimg.com/736x/92/80/c1/9280c111e34752405eb524d4ed0750e6--ian-somerholder-beautiful-men.jpg">
    </div>
```

Answer (score 3):

Defina o tamanho da imagem, igualmente ao da div

```css
.profilepic {
width: 150px;
height: 150px;
border-radius: 50%;
background-image: url(http://1.bp.blogspot.com/-qnQOjPW5TGY/TmjhXuZGBzI/AAAAAAAAHzM/wVzoFozSlg8/s640/paisagem+peaceful_place_by_julie_rc.jpg);
background-size: 150px 150px;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-position: center;

}
```

```html
<div class="profilepic"></div>
```

Answer (score -1):

Pode utilizar [`background-size: cover`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-size) já que está inserindo a url da imagem diretamente no css.

```css
.profilepic {
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: url(https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rpt58.jpg) no-repeat center center;
  background-size: cover
}
```

```html
<div class="profilepic"></div>
```